# Attach listener to Azure Active Directory Microsoft login for Django

Tags: python, django, http, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm writing an app using Django that uses exclusively MS login to authenticate users. I've followed the same structure as the sample code set up at their Django tutorial. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in, where it uses some middleware and Django adapters provided by a seemingly undocumented and unused library they've created at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-samples-common/.

I'm able to grab ID token claims from a request, but what I want to do is attach a listener to login to manipulate or add an entry in a database (regarding user information). I can't figure out a way to hook something to login.

For reference, I created and am using a basic AAD tenant, and MS automatically redirects users after authentication to localhost/auth/redirect with some GET parameters like "code", "state", and "session state".